# Microsoft IIS Administration API - Install SSL

Tags: iis

I've installed the IIS Admin API, it seems to run by default on port 55539

http://localhost:55539/connect

I need to access this externally and ideally want to use SSL, but I can't find this site running within IIS, when I group my sites by port there are no sites bound to anything other than ports 80 and 443.

Does this run outside of IIS? If so is it possible to use an SSL cert with it.

Thanks

Comment: You should read its documentation to learn how to configure it properly, not asking around. Tutorials are usually not discussed here on Stack Overflow. BTW, many things can hook to Windows HTTP API directly, without creating sites on IIS, which you might memorize.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft IIS Administration API is a REST API that enables users to configure and monitor their IIS web servers. The IIS instance can be configured with any HTTP client by installing the API on the IIS computer.

You may have misunderstood, IIS Administration API is not a website hosted in IIS, it is a standalone application running on its own port. By default, it runs on port 55539 and is not associated with any particular website in IIS.

Every call to the API requires an access token in the request header, and the service cannot be used from outside the machine unless the port it listens on is opened. You can refer this link to know [how to connect to the Management Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/management-portal/connecting).

In addtion, certificates provide a mechanism for web servers to prove their identity and secure communication channels. The Certificate API is essential for creating websites that serve content over HTTPS. All certificates belong to a certificate store. A list of available certificate stores can be retrieved from the certificate stores endpoint `/api/certificates/stores`. These certificate stores have a claims property that specifies what operations are allowed on the certificates within the store. You can configure it through the certificates section of the [application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/configuration/appsettings.json) file. **Currently the certificate store only supports read operations. In the future the API may support importing, exporting, deleting and creating certificates.**